# Multilingual Database table design

Tags: sql, database-design, multilingual, subquery

I am using the following approach for a multilingual database, where the fields I am using such as `occupation`, `eye_color`, `countries_visited`, `music_liked`, etc., are pre-determined options from lists that have already been translated in different languages. User can only choose from the options presented. For example: `Table 1` has all the basic non translatable information. `Table 2` has the translation values for eye color and `Table 3` has the translation values for Type of Music user likes:

```
TABLE1: (userlist) 
USERID| FNAME| EYECOLOR_ID| MUSICLIKE_ID
"100", "JOHN", "1", "1,3,5"

TABLE2:(eyevalues)
EYECOLOR_ID| EYE_ENGLISH| EYE_SPANISH| EYE_FRENCH
"1", "BLUE", ÄZUL", "BLEU"
ETC...

TABLE3:(musicvalues)
MUSICLIKE_ID| MUSIC_ENGLISH| MUSIC_SPANISH| MUSIC_FRENCH
"1","ROCK MUSIC", "MUSICA ROCK" "MUSIQUE ROCK"
"2","LATIN  MUSIC", "MUSICA LATINA" "MUSIQUE LATIN"
"3","POP MUSIC", "MUSICA POP" "MUSIQUE POP"

ETC...
```

By doing a left join query I can pull the correct translation easily for eye color because there is only 1 value for eye color. But how do I present the different values for MUSICLIKE? Is there a better approach to what I am trying to do?

I hope the question is clear....

Comment: you need to normalise the music like fk in user list using a junction table for the m:n relationship and not store it as a 'list'.

Comment: I am sorry, I am just an amateur... do you mean by normalizing music, creating an additional table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MUSICLIKE_ID` column of the `USERS` table you have what appears to be a list of IDs, this does not meet normal form and is horrible to work with in the long run. You should remove this.

Instead implement a many to many relationship such as 'many users like many music genres' using a junction table (aka bridge/map tables).

In this case the table would be `USER_MUSIC ( user_id , music_id )`. n.b. you would create a unique constraint covering both columns.

Then when you come to joining the tables you go via the junction table.

```
select u.user_name, m.music_english
from users as u
join user_music as um
on u.user_id = um.user_id
join music as m
on um.music_id = m.music_id
```